# Convert Natural Language to Cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, knowledge-graph

I'm working on creating a knowledge graph of relationships between entities in emails, using neo4j. I now need to convert natural language search queries into cypher queries. I have been unable to find anything concrete with regards to this. How do I proceed?

Comment: This question is much too broad for Stackoverflow. You may want to try the [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm working on that to!, let me know if you want to colaborate

Answer (score 6):

Great paper on this topic: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/119708/1078222310-MIT.pdf?sequence=1

This involves, at the core:

- Named Entity Recognition (custom NER with SpaCy, https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-named-entity-recognition-using-spacy-7140ebbb3718)
- Named Entity Linking (with a Knowledge Base, https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/entity-linking-a-primary-nlp-task-for-information-extraction-22f9d4b90aa8)
- Relation Extraction (https://medium.com/@andreasherman/different-ways-of-doing-relation-extraction-from-text-7362b4c3169e) (although, the RE method in the aforementioned paper seems more concrete)

I'm not an expert on this at all- just beginning to learn about NLP, graph databases, etc.

So if anyone has additional resources or notes on the ones I shared, please contribute!

Comment: Any suggestions on training data set , example natural language and corresponding cypher query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Text2Cypher: Natural Language Queries](https://neo4j.com/labs/neodash/2.3/user-guide/extensions/natural-language-queries/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PaidSearch&utm_campaign=Evergreenutm_content=EMEA-Search-SEMCE-DSA-None-SEM-SEM-NonABM&utm_term=&utm_adgroup=DSA-use-cases&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiArfauBhApEiwAeoB7qEL6aORiv5MHJw0He2enESYeCMnEIW5yVy3KF4Luinen4_GGNKdpUxoCe-8QAvD_BwE) extension to do so.
Remember that in order to use the extension you need to [install APOC library](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/installation/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PaidSearch&utm_campaign=Evergreenutm_content=EMEA-Search-SEMCE-DSA-None-SEM-SEM-NonABM&utm_term=&utm_adgroup=DSA-use-cases&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwzN-vBhAkEiwAYiO7oFvEu7BlLU065GUIHjB-BydsLVQ_AOKAkyx8Xr8GaeREXGFp_B-_3RoCJKQQAvD_BwE) on your graph database and restart it beforehand.